# Hidden data in a form, but PrimaryKey or ForeignKey

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a view that edits an instance of model Foo.  It's either called with one arg (form post) or three args (initial request to edit the object):

```
def edit_it(request, key1_id=-1, key2_id=-1):
```

where `key1_id` and `key2_id` identify the particular instance to edit.  On entry, I check to see if I've been called from a form post or from a link

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    key1_id = request.key1_id    # first thing that doesn't work
    key2_id = request.key2_id    # (also doesn't work)
    foo = Foo.objects.get(key1=key1_id, key2=key2_id)
    form = Foo(request.POST, instance=foo)
    ...
else:
    foo = Foo.objects.get(key1=key1_id, key2=key2_id)
    form = Foo(instance=foo)
```

In my template, I explicitly insert `<input type="hidden" ... >` for `key1_id` and `key2_id`.  So it seems reasonable that key1_id and key2_id should be in request.POST somewhere, but I've not found it poking through code, docs, and google.

Or am I completely confused and I should do this differently?  I tried specifying the key[12]_id fields in the model with `"widget=forms.HiddenInput"`, but widget doesn't work here:  `key1_id` is a primary key and `key2_id` is ForeignKey whose job is just to avoid fishing for other people's objects by modifying `key1_id` in the URL.

The html that results (now slightly modified thanks to the suggestion to maintain the args to the post) is this:

```
<table> 
  <form action="/seededit/u=2/sh=14" method="post">
   <div style='display:none'>
   <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken'
    value='19a559c496e637cdbf3132ce8e147cc4' /></div> 

[...]

<tr> 
  <td><input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="2" /> 
      <input type="hidden" name="shareable_id" value="14" /></td> 
  <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></td> 
</tr> 
</form> 
</table> 
</p>
```

Comment: Can you show us everything from the opening `<form>` to the closing `</form>`? That will narrow the number of potential issues.

Comment: Why not make your form post to the URL with key_1 and key_2, as you do with the edit link?

Comment: @RobAllen -   <form action="/seededit" method="post"> ... <tr> 
  <td><input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="2" /> 
      <input type="hidden" name="shareable_id" value="15" /></td> 
  <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" /></td> 
</tr> 
</form>

Comment: I see the <form> and <table> are swapped (consistently), but that shouldn't be a problem for django.

Comment: Also, could you post the contents of the `request.POST`? It seems to me it should be in there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - That works perfectly simplifies my code as well.  Thanks!

Comment: jro - btw, how does one get the full contents of request.POST?  (I think DR provided a perfect solution, but it would still be interesting to understand what was happening.)

Comment: @jma, paste the html into your question please

Comment: Since no one mentioned it: the `request.key1_id` and `request.key2_id` don't work because they are not attributes of `request`; they are straight arguments that were passed to your view so you reference them as simply `key1_id` and `key2_id`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt - ah, right, thanks.

I consider this question answered now.  Since all the discussion has taken place in the comment area, and SO encourages us not to use "AYQ" if it's answered in the comments, I'm not clear how to signal that the question is answered.  So just a comment here to say thanks to all.

Comment: Because I hate questions with 0 answers, it makes it harder to find which questions need answered, I've summarized below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not `request.key2_id` It's `request.POST['key2_id`]` request.POST is a QueryDict that acts like a dictionary, so print request.POST will show you a dictionary.

That being said, you can still use/define those fileds as HiddenInput and then use django's form validation to make sure that they are the right type/exist etc. There are loads of options when it comes to handling forms, request variables, and validation.

Comment: Right, thanks for summarizing.  The solution I opted for, which was super easy, was to embed the data in the URL, as suggested by Daniel Roseman in the comments of the original question.  That wouldn't scale to needing a lot of data, but for a simple pointer to what object the current form addresses, it's beautifully simple.

Comment: Yup, that's what I do most of the time too.